# Cannot install packages using Nuget

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, windows-10-universal, il2cpp

I am unable to install any packages to my Unity UWP project ouput in visual stuio using nuget(VS solution is in C++).
I get
"Could not install package 'xxxxx'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

I have unity version 2019 and Visual studio 2019 installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so the sentence "but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework" says all...

Comment: Yeah. I get it but the fix for this issue?? Any suggestion how to tackle it?

Comment: the nuget package functionning with Unity are rare . And often its stipuled... You could use Nuget but with package dedicaced to unity.. After another test is to reference the dll directly in your project to see what its happens. so unity is C# and here you want to install C++ package. Its already complex in VSstudio for C# so for Unity....